# Incrementing index in table for each data row

Tags: typescript

So I've been wanting to make a table of data and I want to number it. The way the table should look like is the following: 
**No. | Name | Surname | Age**
1   | Alex | Peter   | 25 
2   | Joe  | Johnson | 30

What the json would look like:

```
{
"name": "Alex",
"surname": Peter",
"age": 25
}
{
"name": "Joe",
"surname": "Johnson",
"age": 30
}
```

I'd want to have a function that would be re-used for each data row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one table row component and reuse it when iterating over your data.

```
const TableRow = ({ rowNo, name, surname, age }) => {
  <tr>
    <td>{rowNo}</td>
    <td>{name}</td>
    <td>{surname}</td>
    <td>{age}</td>
  </tr>;
};

const Table = () => {
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      {data.map((row, index) => {
        const rowNum = index + 1;
        return <TableRow key={rowNum} rowNo={rowNum} {...row} />;
      })}
    </table>
  );
};
```